# How do I ensure that elements inside the dropdown menu can only be selected once in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

```
class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final IconData icon;
  const CardWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.color,
    required this.icon,
  });

  @override
  State<CardWidget> createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {    

  final List<String> items = [
        'Key 1',
        'Key 2',
        'Key 3',
        'Key 4',
      ];
      String? selectedValue;
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              color: widget.color,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    widget.icon,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 32,
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      widget.title,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton2(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      hint: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Select a Key',
                                style: dropdownTitle,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      items: items
                          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: item,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    item,
                                    style: dropdownItems,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                      value: selectedValue,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedValue = value as String;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 20,
                      iconEnabledColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 10, 88),
                      iconDisabledColor: Colors.grey,
                      buttonHeight: 40,
                      buttonWidth: 135,
                      buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15,
                        right: 15,
                      ),
                      buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black26,
                        ),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                      ),
                      buttonElevation: 2,
                      itemHeight: 40,
                      itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
                      dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
                      dropdownWidth: 200,
                      dropdownPadding: null,
                      dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      dropdownElevation: 8,
                      scrollbarRadius: const Radius.circular(10),
                      scrollbarThickness: 6,
                      scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
                      offset: const Offset(-20, 0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

CardWidget I created.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
              CardWidget(
                      title: 'Mute',
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 38, 25),
                      icon: Icons.volume_off_outlined,
                    ),
                CardWidget(
                      title: 'Mute',
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 38, 25),
                      icon: Icons.volume_off_outlined,
                    ),
              CardWidget(
                      title: 'Mute',
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 38, 25),
                      icon: Icons.volume_off_outlined,
                    ),
               CardWidget(
                      title: 'Mute',
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 38, 25),
                      icon: Icons.volume_off_outlined,
                    ),
              ],
            ),
```

The homepage where I use CardWidget.

[image]

I can call my list and select the elements inside the list.

[image]

However, as seen in the image, it can be active even though 'key 1' is selected in all dropdowns. What I'm dealing with is for example 'key 1' is selected in the first dropdown, if 'key 1' is selected in the second dropdown it will just show it there. The second dropdown should not write 'key 1' under the menu, it should write in the last selected one. Leave the first one blank.

Comment: are you using some package for DropdownButtonWidget

Comment: I am using https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2 this package.

Comment: Can you include sample scaffold body with all. seems it is missing

Comment: I added all my code.

Comment: There will be 5 drowpdown on scaffold ?

Comment: There will be 4 pieces. I showed how I defined a single CardWidget on the homepage so I wouldn't write the same code. As in the second photo, there is a card design with 4 dropdown menus side by side. There are dropdowns with key numbers from 1 to 4 each.

Comment: Just add the CardWidget 4 times and it will display the image in the second photo.

Comment: I edited my code again.

Comment: OK Got it, let me see what can i do for you

Comment: The question is supper cool

Comment: I've been trying for 3-4 hours, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I started with map, but it was little chaotic to understand for others , then convert to model class to make it  readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Removed selected Item from others dropdown selection:*
I am using Valunotifer  to simplify the snippet and the logic is

```dart
onChanged: (value) {
    final index =
        cardsNotifier.value.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsNotifier.value.length; i++) {
      if (index != i && cardsNotifier.value[i].selectedItem == value) {
        cardsNotifier.value[i].selectedItem = null;
      }
    }
    cardsNotifier.value[index].selectedItem = value;

    cardsNotifier.value = cardsNotifier.value.toList();
  },
```

Test widget

```dart
class FA extends StatefulWidget {
  const FA({super.key});

  @override
  State<FA> createState() => _FAState();
}

class CardHelper {
  final int id;
  String? selectedItem;
  CardHelper({
    required this.id,
    this.selectedItem,
  });
}

ValueNotifier<List<CardHelper>> cardsNotifier = ValueNotifier(List.generate(
    4,
    (index) => CardHelper(
          id: index,
        )));

class _FAState extends State<FA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < cardsNotifier.value.length; i++)
          CardWidget(
            title: 'Mute',
            id: cardsNotifier.value[i].id,
          ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  final int id;

  const CardWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              itemBuilder(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ValueListenableBuilder<List<CardHelper>> itemBuilder() {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<List<CardHelper>>(
      valueListenable: cardsNotifier,
      builder: (context, data, child) => DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Select a Key',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          items: ['Key 1', 'Key 2', 'Key 3', 'Key 4']
              .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        item,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
          value: data[id].selectedItem,
          onChanged: (value) {
            final index =
                cardsNotifier.value.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);

            for (int i = 0; i < cardsNotifier.value.length; i++) {
              if (index != i && cardsNotifier.value[i].selectedItem == value) {
                cardsNotifier.value[i].selectedItem = null;
              }
            }
            cardsNotifier.value[index].selectedItem = value;

            cardsNotifier.value = cardsNotifier.value.toList();
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
          ),
          iconSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Remove selected item from dropdown**

I am using a helper class for simplification

```dart
class CardHelper {
  final int id;
  final List<String> items;
  final String? selectedItem;

  CardHelper({
    required this.id,
    required this.items,
    this.selectedItem,
  });
}
```

And the  `CardWidget` widget take data as input and provide a callback with selected item.

```dart
class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  final Function(String?) selectedItemCallback;
   .....
  const CardWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.items,
```

And onChanged will be

```dart
items: widget.items
    .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: item,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              item,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ))
    .toList(),
value: selectedValue,
onChanged: (value) {
  widget.selectedItemCallback(value);
```

Now for the parent widget, we will create a list  for cards

```dart
  final cards = List.generate(
      4,
      (index) =>
          CardHelper(id: index, items: ['Key 1', 'Key 2', 'Key 3', 'Key 4']));
```

And rest logic lies

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    CardWidget(
      title: 'Mute',
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 38, 25),
      icon: Icons.volume_off_outlined,
      items: cards[i].items,
      selectedItemCallback: (p0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cards.length; j++) {
          if (i == j) continue;
          cards[j].items.remove(p0);
        }
        setState(() {});
      },
    ),
```

---

Play widget

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: FA()));
}

class FA extends StatefulWidget {
  const FA({super.key});

  @override
  State<FA> createState() => _FAState();
}

class CardHelper {
  final int id;
  final List<String> items;
  final String? selectedItem;

  CardHelper({
    required this.id,
    required this.items,
    this.selectedItem,
  });
}

class _FAState extends State<FA> {
  final cards = List.generate(
      4,
      (index) =>
          CardHelper(id: index, items: ['Key 1', 'Key 2', 'Key 3', 'Key 4']));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
            CardWidget(
              title: 'Mute',
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 38, 25),
              icon: Icons.volume_off_outlined,
              items: cards[i].items,
              selectedItemCallback: (p0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cards.length; j++) {
                  if (i == j) continue;
                  cards[j].items.remove(p0);
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final IconData icon;
  final Function(String?) selectedItemCallback;
  const CardWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.items,
    required this.title,
    required this.color,
    required this.icon,
    required this.selectedItemCallback,
  });

  @override
  State<CardWidget> createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {
  String? selectedValue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          color: widget.color,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Icon(
                widget.icon,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 32,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                ),
              ),
              DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton2(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Select a Key',
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  items: widget.items
                      .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: item,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                item,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  value: selectedValue,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    widget.selectedItemCallback(value);
                    setState(() {
                      selectedValue = value as String;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 20,
                  iconEnabledColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 10, 88),
                  iconDisabledColor: Colors.grey,
                  buttonHeight: 40,
                  buttonWidth: 135,
                  buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15,
                    right: 15,
                  ),
                  buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                    ),
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  ),
                  buttonElevation: 2,
                  itemHeight: 40,
                  itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
                  dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
                  dropdownWidth: 200,
                  dropdownPadding: null,
                  dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  dropdownElevation: 8,
                  scrollbarRadius: const Radius.circular(10),
                  scrollbarThickness: 6,
                  scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
                  offset: const Offset(-20, 0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is also `enabled` option on `DropdownMenuItem` can act disable state with showing the items

Comment: A very successful solution. Thank you so much. But there is a problem somewhere. For example, let's say key 1 is selected for the first Card. Key 1 should appear on the second card. If the user selects key 1 for the second card, key 1 should now be written under the 2nd card. But with this code, I can only select 1 key once.

Comment: you like to override the value if user select 1st key on second filed being seleted ?

Comment: No, I want all values ​​to be valid on all dropdowns. If the user selects 'key 1' in the first card and wants to select 'key 1' in the second card, the key1 on the first card should be deleted instead of the default text "select a key" or it should be blank.

Comment: ok last selected will be prioritized, I think I've got ?

Comment: I will reach you soon

Comment: Yes, you think right. I am waiting for your reply. Thank you so much.

Comment: Updated, kinda busy with my semester final 

Comment: Alright. I wish you success in your exams.

Comment: test update part(top), that should answer your post

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the solution I wanted. I just want to ask a little something. As an example, since the title of the cardWidget you created is in the for loop, it gives the "Mute" title to all of these cards. But I will give names to each of these cards separately. How can I do that?

Comment: You can a list and then pass like `muteList[i]`, Or better create a filed on model class